# How can i get selected day, month, year and hours,minute from React Native datepicker every time i pick it?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-native, datetime

```
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';

export default class App extends Component {
   static navigationOptions= ({navigation}) =>({
          header: null
    });
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      date: '',
      time: '',

    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e) => {console.log('onStartShouldSetPanResponder'); return true;},
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (e) => {console.log('onMoveShouldSetPanResponder'); return true;},
      onPanResponderGrant: (e) => console.log('onPanResponderGrant'),
      onPanResponderMove: (e) => console.log('onPanResponderMove'),
      onPanResponderRelease: (e) => console.log('onPanResponderRelease'),
      onPanResponderTerminate: (e) => console.log('onPanResponderTerminate')
    });


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to react-native-datepicker example!
        </Text>
        <DatePicker
          style={{width: 200}}
          date={this.state.date}
          mode="date"
          placeholder="placeholder"
          format="DD-MM-YYYY"
          minDate="01-01-1930"
          maxDate="31-12-2099"
          confirmBtnText="Confirm"
          cancelBtnText="Cancel"
          iconSource={require('./google_calendar.png')}
          onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date});}}
        />
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>date: {this.state.date}</Text>
        <DatePicker
          style={{width: 200}}
          date={this.state.time}
          mode="time"
          placeholder="placeholder"
          format="HH:mm"
          confirmBtnText="Confirm"
          cancelBtnText="Cancel"
          minuteInterval={10}
          onDateChange={(time) => {this.setState({time: time});}}
        />
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>time: {this.state.time}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

How can i get from this data day,month,year,hour and minute ?

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Comment: what are you getting in your `this.state.date` variable???

Comment: this.state = { date:''} selected date get like 01-11-1933

Answer (score 2):

You can use different builtin functions to extract Day, Month, Year.

For e.g

```
getDateAttributes(){
    let d = new Date(this.state.date);  // i assume your date as 01-11-1933
    d.getDate(); // 11
    d.getMonth(); // 0  month is like array so you have to do +1 for correct month
    d.getFullYear(); // 1933
}
```

Comment: Can you help me ? how can i run this function

Comment: How can i get hour and minutes ? in datetime

Comment: After the Selection of Date

Answer (score 0):

Just remplace `mode='date'`,
with : `mode='datetime'` in your `DatePicker` Component.

Check the [props](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker#properties) for more informations